# Cannot open source file "SDL2/SDL.h" Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, sdl, sdl-2

Help !
I installed SDL2 , I set up all Directions in its place and added lib too
But it says Cannot open source file "SDL2/SDL.h" I did what I can do
Please Help

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJOAT.png)

I installed SLD2 and Prepared all directions in Microsoft vs but still nothing the same proplem

Comment: Did you set up your Include Directories in project settings?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ***Cannot open source file "SDL2/SDL.h"*** Means the directory you added to your `C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories` setting was incorrect or you did not apply it to all configurations.

Comment: I fixed it I removed (SDL2/) from <SLD2/SDL.h> because the header file that called SDL.h wasn't in the folder SLD2 it was directly in the include folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah I fixed it
I forgot that / set up directions
So SDL2/SDL.h means that the header file is in folder called SDL2 and the SDL.h header file was in the include folder so SDL.h was attached directly and all what I did was removing SDL2/ from the header file

```
#include <*SDL2/*SDL.h>
```

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered.